# URI scheme for twitter on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, twitter, uri-scheme

There is little information about the uri scheme for the native wp (8.1) twitter app so I took this from the iPhone documentation:
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Twitter

This is my C# code, both do not crash and open the twitter application. Just not with the specified user or with the id of the status.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this still unsupported by the Twitter app on Windows Phone?

```
private async void OpenTweet(TwitterStatus s)
{
    //Uri ut = new Uri("twitter://status?id=" + s.Id); // did not work
    Uri ut = new Uri("twitter://user?screen_name=" + s.Author); // does not work
    bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(ut);
}
```

Comment: can you please provide twitter share uri schema if u know..thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Windows Phone is no longer a product. This question won't be answered. Also, an answer to this question wouldn't help anyone in the future.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because WP is no longer a product (it was my own question)